# Can you apply the Euler-Lagrange equations when trying to find the extrema of a (real valued) functional of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have a complex valued function $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and I want to minimise a functional of the form: $ J = \int_{0}^{1} g(|f(x)|^2) \,dx $ where $g$ is some function. So the functional $J$ is real, even though $f$ is complex. Can I apply the Euler Lagrange equations and get an ODE in terms of  $f$ or $f^*$, or is this unjustified because $f$ is complex valued?

Comment: why not simply minimize $\int_0^1g(h(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$ where $h(x)$ is  a positive real function. Then the solution can be any function so that $|f(x)|=h(x)$.

Comment: I think the crux of the matter is that when finding the Euler Lagrange equation for $J$, differentiating $|f(x)|^2 $ gives $2f^*$, so the Euler Lagrange ODE is complex. Is that ok?

Comment: If you find the $h$ I suggest in my previous comment, you will see that the main problem is that there is no minimizing $f$ since you can multiply $h$ by any function with absolute value $1$.

Comment: I see what you mean. What if, instead, I wanted to minimise $J= \int_{0}^{1} g(|f(x)|^2,|f'(x)|^2) \,dx$ subject to fixed $I= \int_{0}^{1} |f'(x)|^2 \,dx$? Then a minimum could exist and my initial question still stands.

Comment: Why should the fact that $f$ is complex valued cause a problem? The equations to be solved will be set to $0$, which is also in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I just am not familiar with using Euler-Lagrange methods with a complex valued function. If it is indeed ok, is there anywhere I can read up on it?